# Evaluating a user's input with a set of randomly generated string values in c#

Tags: c#

I have a set of randomly generated incorrect string(words) that appears to a user and I want to evaluate the user suggestion or input with the correct word. I can't find my way out on how to match the user's input to the correct word, someone helping me would really be relieving.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random Rnd = new Random();
        string[] words = { "M_R_", "I_R_E_" };
        Console.WriteLine(words[Rnd.Next(0, words.Length)]);


        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        int points = 0;
        if ((words[Rnd.Next(0, words.Length)]).Equals("I_R_E_") && name == "Israel")
        {
            points += 5;

            Console.WriteLine("Marks: {0}", points);
            Console.WriteLine("You won!!!!");
        }
        else if ((words[Rnd.Next(0, words.Length)]).Equals("M_R_") && name == "Mark")
        {
            points += 5;

            Console.WriteLine("Marks: {0}", points);
            Console.WriteLine("You won!!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that every call of Rnd.Next creates a new random number.

Comment: you should do switch - case if you plan to add more and more words[]. switch(Rnd.Next(0, words.Length)]){case 0:break; case 1: break;} and so on. Else you could use use logical OR in your if to avoid redundant code. if(((words[Rnd.Next(0, words.Length)]).Equals("I_R_E_") && name == "Israel") || ((words[Rnd.Next(0, words.Length)]).Equals("M_R_") && name == "Mark")) {}

Comment: @Nitro: Please put your comment into an answer, explain the solution and reformat the code. That would be great.

Comment: @Peter Done, hope that's okay for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do this:

```
var word = words[Rnd.Next(0, words.Length)];
Console.WriteLine(word);
...

if (word.Equals("I_R_E_") && name == "Israel")
...
```

Otherwise you're always calling next on random so its probable you won't be comparing the correct string.

Answer (score 1):

Store the random number generated and use in your processes.

```
        Random Rnd = new Random();
        string[] words = { "M_R_", "I_R_E_" };
        var randomNumber = Rnd.Next(0, words.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(words[randomNumber]);


        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        int points = 0;
        if ((words[randomNumber]).Equals("I_R_E_") && name == "Israel")
        {
            points += 5;

            Console.WriteLine("Marks: {0}", points);
            Console.WriteLine("You won!!!!");
        }
        else if ((words[randomNumber]).Equals("M_R_") && name == "Mark")
        {
            points += 5;

            Console.WriteLine("Marks: {0}", points);
            Console.WriteLine("You won!!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments you should summarize your code to avoid redundant code and make it more readable. And of course you should save the random number in a variable to avoid that you get new number in ever if.

**If with logical or operator**

```
Random Rnd = new Random();
string[] words = { "M_R_", "I_R_E_" };
int points = 0;
int randomNumber = Rnd.Next(0, words.Length);

Console.WriteLine(randomNumber);  

Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
string name = Console.ReadLine();

var word = words[randomNumber];

if((word.Equals("I_R_E_") && name == "Israel")
|| (word.Equals("M_R_") && name == "Mark")) // you can add words here
{
    points += 5;
    Console.WriteLine("Marks: {0}\nYou won!!!!", points);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect");
}
```

If the `Length` of `words[]` are going to increase you'll just have to add a single line to this if and the job is done here.

Another way would be a **dictionary or list** or something similar I guess.

```
Dictionary<int, string> words = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    {0, "Israel"},
    {1, "Mark"},
    {2, "Foo"},
    {3, "Bar"} // add more if you want
};

Random Rnd = new Random();
int randomNumber = Rnd.Next(0, words.Count); // Attention! Dict, list etc. use .Count not .Length!
int points = 0;

Console.WriteLine(randomNumber);  

Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
string name = Console.ReadLine();    

string word = "";
if(!words.TryGetValue(randomNumber, out word)) return; // whoops index not found in dictionary!

if(word.Equals(name))
{
    points += 5;
    Console.WriteLine("Marks: {0}\nYou won!!!!", points);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect");
```

In that case you dont't even have to write more code than the new word inside the dictionary.